# TS vs TRS cables to connect mixer to Main Out interface

Tags: mixer

I have a Behringer Xenyx 1002FX mixer and I want to connect it to my speaker (Protech CB400A).
The mixer's interfaces of "Main Out" are Mono.
But I have a TRS cable (PL Stereo) to XLR Male.
Can I connect this cable although the interface is Mono?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends which wire connects the R on the jack to which pin on XLR. Nothing will go bang if you try it, but you may need to simply disconnect the wire from the  R on the jack.

Comment: "Mixer to speaker" sounds like it's an integrated amp in the speaker - it probably would much prefer a balanced line. Unbalancing it might be noisy & prone to interference. How far is your cable run? [A quick google sys yup, that's a 400w integrated amp.]

Comment: Tetsujin... You're right. And the length of my cable is 3 meters.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have several similar set ups, and have no need for a balanced line. Simple single core coax works fine. That apart, the mixer doesn't have a balanced 'out'.

Comment: You really ought to properly unbalance the cables if there's no alternative - you don't want meters of stray antenna in there.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use that cable? Probably. Should you? Probably not.

There are TS->XLR cables available, with the pin short-circuit made. You can DIY it with a quick Google.

Alternatively, you can run from the mixer into a DI box with a TS->TS cable (1/4 Mono), then come out of the DI box with an XLR->XLR. That XLR cable will be balanced, and can be as long as you might ever need.